# How to do simple home-automation?

Tags: home-automation

I am looking for some guide, examples, books 
to do simple things (automation) with Ubuntu. Like

- turning on / off the electricity
- open doors
- etc

Any idea would be appreciated,

thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[LinuxMCE](http://www.linuxmce.com/) is a free, open source add-on to Kubuntu.

[Linux Home Automation](http://www.linuxha.com/index.html) has **a lot** of links.

Answer (score 3):

Just this instant I stumpled upon [Open Advanced Process Control](http://www.openapc.com/download.php) (OpenAPC) in an article about [home automation](http://www.pro-linux.de/artikel/2/1482/2,heimautomatisierung-fuer-hardwarebastler.html) in a german Linux online zine.

[image: OpenAPC screenshot]

Looks quite powerful, but also complicated, I guess. Let me know if that's the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

for hardware - check [Arduino controller](http://www.arduino.cc/) - open-source electronics prototyping platform. Plays nice with Ubuntu